# Problem saving data in a modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `modelform` set up for a user to enter his contact info. The validation and `form.is_valid()` method is working, however the `request.POST` data is not being stored to the db, and I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is. Here is what I currently have --

```
# model
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    contact_phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)

class ContactInfoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('contact_email', 'contact_phone', 'website',)

# view
@login_required
def edit_contact(request):
    contact_email = request.user.get_profile().contact_email
    form = ContactInfoForm(initial={'contact_email':contact_email,})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render_to_response(...)

# template
<form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{form}}
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" name="save_changes" value="Save Changes" ></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error might be the instance you're calling in your ModelForm. You need to use a UserProfile instance, but you're using a User instance. The following might work (untested):

```
@login_required
def edit_contact(request):
    contact_email = request.user.get_profile().contact_email
    form = ContactInfoForm(initial={'contact_email':contact_email,})
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(contact_email=contact_email)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactInfoForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render_to_response(...)
```

Comment: I just figured that out and was about to post that answer, thanks for the help.